# Regarding the binomial formula

Tags: factoring

$(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$

so if I have:

$-(a^2 + b^2)=$

$= -a^2 - b^2$

Can I write it like:

$(-a^2) - b^2 = $

$= (-a + b)(-a - b)$

Comment: No, $(-a)\cdot (-a)\neq -a^2$ in general.

Comment: ik. But it's not like we can't have '-1'  being multiplied to some number's square. Like: -1*(2)^2= -4

Comment: Replacing $-a$ in $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ gives $(-a+b)(-a-b)=(-a)^2-b^2=a^2-b^2$.

Comment: oh right thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful: $-a^2$ is “the negative of the square of $a$”, not “the square of the negative of $a$”. The latter would be written $(-a)^2$.

Exponents have higher priority over operations based on addition (such as taking the negative). Thus $-a^2$ is computed by first taking the square of $a$, then the negative.

By the way, $(-a)^2=a^2$, which equals $-a^2$ if and only if $a=0$.

Also, notice that
$$
(-a+b)(-a-b)=(-1)(a-b)(-1)(a+b)=(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2
$$
that can be obtained also with the standard
$$
(-a+b)(-a-b)=(-a)^2-b^2=a^2-b^2
$$

Comment: Yeah so mainly it is wrong because (−a)^2−b^2 =/= a^2−b^2 yet using  '(a+b)(a−b)=a^2−b^2'   for   '-(a^2 +b^2)'  proves it true.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$, therefore $$(-a+b)(-a-b)=(-a)^2-b^2=a^2-b^2\neq -a^2-b^2$$